# How to add image into compositor?

Tags: node-editor, uv-image-editor, compositing-nodes

I recently rendered a scene in blender after following a BlenderGuru tutorial and made sure to save the image. After closing Blender and going back in, I am able to open the image up in the UV Image Editor (below)

[image]

However, after selecting "compositing" and going into the node editor, I can't seem to view the image with the "viewer" node. The only option I seem to have is to re-render the whole scene again in order to see this in the node editor?

[image]

Comment: Render Layers is a node which provides information from Render Layers, and it's empty unless render was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an add Input>Image node.

If the image is already loaded in the UV/Image editor all you have to do is select it. If not you have to import it.

[image]

Comment: I have used the image node, however the next step in the tutorial was using "IndexMa" from the Render Layers node, which the Image node doesn't have. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well that is a different question that should be asked separately. Basically you need to save in a format that can save such information: OpenEXR, and you need to explicitly save such information by connecting the appropriate sockets to an output node. Please ask in a different post the goal of this site is not to give personalized-per-project support, but to answer concrete questions.